# What is $E^E$ in the specification of monoid $(E^E, \circ )$ of the functions from set $E$ to itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

In Wikipedia article about [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) there is a specification of monoid $(E^E, \circ )$ of the functions from set $E$ to itself.

What is $E^E$ in this specification? Conceptually and, maybe, with some simple example, e.g. on a set of two elements.

Comment: It is the set of functions from $E$ to itself, as you said. Could you specify what is your question? I read the Wikipedia page but I can't see what you need. I don't want to be rough! Just help you better :) welcome on MSE!

Comment: I do not understand the notation $E^E$. If I had $E=\{0, 1\}$, e.g., what would be $E^E$?

Comment: I reckon that these are *all possible* total functions from $E$ to $E$, i.e. $\{\langle 1, 1  \rangle, \langle  2, 1  \rangle \}$ (both inputs mup to 1), and 3 other possible combinations, but I did not find the meaning of notation $A^B$ in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, we define $A^B$ to be the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$. In your particular example, we have $A = B = E$ and so the set can be given a monoid structure by defining the operation to be composition.

To answer your question from the comments: "What is $E^E$ when $E = \{0, 1\}$?"
Consider the following four functions $f_1, \ldots, f_4 : E \to E$

1. The identity function, i.e., $f_1(x) = x$ for all $x \in E$,
2. The constant $0$ function, i.e., $f_2(x) = 0$ for all $x \in E$,
3. The constant $1$ function, i.e., $f_3(x) = 1$ for all $x \in E$,
4. The switch function, i.e., $f_4(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x = 1 \\1 & x = 0\end{cases}.$

Then, $E^E = \{f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4\}$.

It would be a good exercise to verify which elements are idempotents. (There's only one which isn't.)

Comment: Very clear and exhaustive, thank you!